# In a ThreadJob, how to access classes defined in the main thread?

Tags: powershell, class, jobs

In ThreadJobs I fail to use custom object classes defined in the main thread.

The script below highlights the problems I encounter and the questions they raise.

```
class People {
    [string] $firstName
    [string] $lastName
    [string] $city
    #
    static [hashtable] $myFriends = @{}
    #
    People (
        [string] $firstName,
        [string] $lastName,
        [string] $city
    ) {
        $this.firstName = $firstName
        $this.lastName = $lastName
        $this.city = $city
        Write-Host "Adding $firstName $lastName"
        [People]::myFriends[ "$firstName $lastName" ] = $this
    }
    #
    [string] List ( ) {
        return "$($this.firstName) $($this.lastName)"
    }
    #
    static [void] ListAll ( ) {
        foreach ( $friend in [People]::myFriends.values ) {
            Write-Host "$('{0,-23:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}' -f $(Get-Date)) $($friend.firstName) $($friend.lastName)"
        }
    }
}
#
$JobScriptBlock1 = {
    Write-Host "$('{0,-23:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}' -f $(Get-Date)) Job1 starting"
    try {
        foreach ( $friend in [People]::myFriends.values ) {
            Write-Host "$('{0,-23:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}' -f $(Get-Date)) $($friend.firstName) $($friend.lastName)"
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host ($_ | Out-String)
    }
}
#
$JobScriptBlock2 = {
    Write-Host "$('{0,-23:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}' -f $(Get-Date)) Job2 starting"
    try {
        [People]::ListAll()
        Write-Host 'Individually'
        foreach ( $friend in [People]::myFriends.values ) {
            Write-Host "$('{0,-23:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}' -f $(Get-Date)) $($friend.List())"
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host ($_ | Out-String)
    }
}
#
$JobScriptBlock3 = {
    param ( $peopleClass )
    Write-Host "$('{0,-23:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}' -f $(Get-Date)) Job3 starting"
    try {
        foreach ( $friend in $peopleClass::myFriends.values ) {
            Write-Host "$('{0,-23:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}' -f $(Get-Date)) $($friend.firstName) $($friend.lastName)"
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host ($_ | Out-String)
    }
}
#
$JobScriptBlock4 = {
    param ( $peopleClass )
    Write-Host "$('{0,-23:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}' -f $(Get-Date)) Job4 starting"
    try {
        $peopleClass::ListAll()
        Write-Host 'Individually'
        foreach ( $friend in $peopleClass::myFriends.values ) {
            Write-Host "$('{0,-23:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}' -f $(Get-Date)) $($friend.List())"
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host ($_ | Out-String)
    }
}
#
$temp = [People]::new( 'Alan', 'Smith', 'New-York' )
$temp = [People]::new( 'John', 'Doe', 'Washington' )
$temp = [People]::new( 'Emily', 'Parker', 'Paris' )
$temp = [People]::new( 'Elodie', 'Nelson', 'Toronto' )
#
Start-ThreadJob -Name 'Job1' -StreamingHost (Get-Host) -ScriptBlock $JobScriptBlock1 | Out-Null
[Threading.Thread]::Sleep( 1000 )
Start-ThreadJob -Name 'Job2' -StreamingHost (Get-Host) -ScriptBlock $JobScriptBlock2 | Out-Null
[Threading.Thread]::Sleep( 1000 )
Start-ThreadJob -Name 'Job3' -StreamingHost (Get-Host) -ScriptBlock $JobScriptBlock3 -ArgumentList ([People]) | Out-Null
[Threading.Thread]::Sleep( 1000 )
Start-ThreadJob -Name 'Job4' -StreamingHost (Get-Host) -ScriptBlock $JobScriptBlock4 -ArgumentList ([People]) | Out-Null
[Threading.Thread]::Sleep( 4000 )
```

The People class is defined in the main thread.

Job1 attempts to access a property of the People class directly.
It fails: Unable to find type [People].

Job2 attempts to access a method of the People class directly.
It fails: Unable to find type [People].

Jobs 3 and 4 are similar to Jobs 1 and 2 respectively, but the People class is passed to them via an argument.
The 2 jobs complete successfully.
However, in Jobs 3 and 4, calling a People method takes more than 250 msec, whereas accessing a property takes less than 1 msec in Job 3.

The script output...

```
Adding Alan Smith
Adding John Doe
Adding Emily Parker
Adding Elodie Nelson
2023-10-19 16:46:31.047 Job1 starting

InvalidOperation:
Line |
   4 |          foreach ( $friend in [People]::myFriends.values ) {
     |                               ~~~~~~~~
     | Unable to find type [People].

2023-10-19 16:46:32.052 Job2 starting

InvalidOperation:
Line |
   4 |          [People]::ListAll()
     |          ~~~~~~~~
     | Unable to find type [People].

2023-10-19 16:46:33.059 Job3 starting
2023-10-19 16:46:33.060 Elodie Nelson
2023-10-19 16:46:33.062 Emily Parker
2023-10-19 16:46:33.062 Alan Smith
2023-10-19 16:46:33.062 John Doe
2023-10-19 16:46:34.056 Job4 starting
2023-10-19 16:46:34.312 Elodie Nelson
2023-10-19 16:46:34.320 Emily Parker
2023-10-19 16:46:34.322 Alan Smith
2023-10-19 16:46:34.323 John Doe
Individually
2023-10-19 16:46:34.323 Elodie Nelson
2023-10-19 16:46:34.578 Emily Parker
2023-10-19 16:46:34.830 Alan Smith
2023-10-19 16:46:35.084 John Doe
```

So my questions are:
Is it necessary to pass classes as parameters to a ThreadJob so that it can use them?
In a ThreadJob, is there any other way of accessing the classes defined in the main Thread?
Why do method calls in Jobs 3 and 4 take so long? How can this be reduced?

Comment: setting up a runspace is not something cheap. if you want performance, specially when multithreading, then powershell is not the right language for you. additionally, you're trying to use instances of your class accessing a reference type member (a hashtable in this case) and that is definitely not thread safe so if you're planning to do this from multiple threads you need to start considering thread safety, at which point your code will slow down even further.

Comment: Yes. In PowerShell, each thread (or job) runs in its own separate *runspace*, which means it has its own separate environment and does not inherit variables, functions, or class definitions from the calling environment. If you need to use a custom class in a job, you either have to define the class within the job or pass it as an argument. With that said, you could make use of **Synchronized Hashtable** but not without the cost of some interthread communication overhead. In other words, you can definetly do it but not without some cost to performance when thiking about thread safety.